# Is there a way to remove the extra header space in Darmstadt theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I have the following sides right now:

[image]

[image]

I want to remove the black and dark green color on my top header and have something similar to the slide below, but except with the colors that I am using.

[image]

Basically, I want to have the same type of structure, but with different colors. Greenish color instead of the blue in the slide 3.

I am using the following codes in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!55!green}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}
```

These are not the complete codes in my preamble, but what I think are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the theme to be different and use the colour theme from `Darmstadt`. So, let's first see what [`Darmstadt` loads](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeDarmstadt.sty):

- `\usecolortheme{orchid}`
- `\usecolortheme{whale}`

Then you also change the `structure` colour:

- `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!55!green}`

So you should be able to load an alternative theme, say `Madrid` with the above changes:

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!55!green}
```

[image]

[image]